# OutOfBoundsException while fetching data

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrTH3.png)

Code

```
        MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity()); // Instantiate a MainDatabasehelper object called myDBHlpr

        Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions(getActivity());

        mMostMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("MostMessagesSent")));
        Log.d("ZZZ", csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("MostMessagesSent")));


        csr.close();
```

Just code for fetching SQLite data, but getting an out of bounds exception in the line.           `mMostMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("MostMessagesSent")));`

Null pointer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yc9Eh.png)

Database helper

```
public Cursor getAllQuestions(FragmentActivity usageSettings) {
    return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

Comment: Show output and/or possible error messages as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or by external link.

Answer (score 0):

You are not moving to an actual row in the Cursor. Therefore when you try to get data you are **before the first row** and hence at the ***impossible to use*** offset of **-1**.

When a Cursor is returned by an SQLiteDatabase method, the Cursor is positioned at a position that is before the first row. This position is -1.

- You can set a Cursor to before the first row using `csr.moveToPosition(-1)` if need be.

Assuming you want to loop through all rows then the following progressively moves to each row in turn until there are no more rows (generally Cursor moveTo???? methods return **true** if the move could be made otherwise they return **false**) (which is why the while loop works for all rows.)

```
    Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions(getActivity());
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        mMostMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex("MostMessagesSent")));
    }
    csr.close();
```

However, that would then only show the very last row in the TextView. If this is an issue and you cannot resolve the issue, you should ask another question.

- Note if the Cursor had no rows, then nothing would be done and the TextView would remain as it was, often you'd want to signify that no data was extracted. -

  - For example, applying this to your code you could have `mMostMessagesSent.setText("No Data Extracted")` before the while loop and therefore the TextView would indicate that no data was extracted, if no data was extracted.

Comment: added a log.d line to check and it showed null... anyreason why?

Comment: the textview is showing blank so i put the log.D code

Comment: At a guess the null pointer would be that you haven't instantiated/set **mMostMessagesSent** (via an appropriate use of **findViewById**). That's assuming that you didn't remove the line `MainData myDBHlpr = new MainData(getActivity()); // Instantiate a MainDatabasehelper object called myDBHlpr` (if you removed the line add it back in)

Comment: The data retrieved is null... But the table exists with 16rows... Count of the rows are 16

Comment: I have added more code can u please check it out please